# How to send token for multipart/form-data to .net core

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I am using Token to validate user in my .net application with Vue.js

For basic get/post api calls, I can able to send my token like this:
updateMainIconPath(data) {

```
return axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_PORTAL_API_URL}Page/update-page-icon-path`,
        data,
        {
            headers: {
                Token: authHeader(),
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });
}
```

But sometimes, I need to send form-data object to .net. Unfortunately, token looks different than the previous one.

```
 updateImageGallery(data) {
    return axios.post(`${process.env.VUE_APP_PORTAL_API_URL}Page/update-image`,
        data,
        {
            headers: {
                Token: JSON.stringify(authHeader()),
                'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
            }
        });
}
```

If I don't use JSON.stringfy, the token looks like [Object object]. If I use it then it looks like not in the string format but in the json format.

How can I sent my token so that it should be string type for both Endpoints?

Comment: What is the type of  `authHeader()`‘s return value? Have you tried converting the token to a string on the front end code?

Comment: @Chen the type is string. Using with multipart/form-data convert token type to object..

Comment: As you said, when used with `multipart/form-data` becomes `[Object object]`, so you need `JSON.stringify(token)`. This will be passed in `Json` format, from which you can take your token, do you have other logic specifying that a string token must be received?